# Trying to accece imgae using metadata-extractor

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

val bytes = it.getByteArray(ExifDirectoryBase.TAG_IMAGE_DATA) returned Unresolved reference: TAG_IMAGE_DATA

val bytes = it.getByteArray(ExifDirectoryBase.TAG_IMAGE_DATA) was expecting to load image from a video url

whats the new way to access it

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen this way of extracting frames out of videos, but you may want to check out [MediaMetadataRetriever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever)

```kotlin
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever

fun getVideoFrame(videoPath: String): Bitmap? {
    val retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
    retriever.setDataSource(videoPath)
    return retriever.getFrameAtTime(-1) // get the first frame
}
```